# How to disable Bird's eye angled view in Bing Maps control version 7

Tags: bing-maps, bing-api

For business use Microsoft charge extra for use of the Bing Maps birds eye angled view, so my client has ask that I disable this option. In verion 6.3 of the control this was easy, there is a map option that can be used to do this: [enter link description here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc470015.aspx)

However, I can't find how to do this using the API with version 7 of the control. The current menu has Birds eye as an option with check boxes show labels and show angled view. Ideally I'd like to disable the option from the menu so that users are only able to view road and aerial views. So it looks like I have two options available:-

1) Hide the show angled view check box somehow with css. The issue here is that I can't get to the HTML content using the IE developer toolbar of firebug as it only displays when selected.
2) Attach to the map maptypechanged event and if birds eye map selected set it back to the map type it used to be.

Both of the above are far from ideal. Does anyone have a suggestion for the best way of doing this?

Comment: Using  firebug identify element I found out the css classes used by the Bing maps control. I then used CSS to remove the Automatic type and also to remove the angled view (but retain the show labels - first child) in the Birds eye type:-
.NavBar_checkControl
{
    display:none;
}
.NavBar_checkControls > .NavBar_checkControl:first-child
{
    display:inherit;
}
.NavBar_itemContainer_auto
{
    display:none;
}

Comment: I then subscribed to the maps maptypechanged event:-
Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(bingMap, 'maptypechanged', mapTypeChange);
And finally reset the birds eye type to aerial view when set;-
function mapTypeChange() {
 var mapTypeId = bingMap.getMapTypeId();
 if (mapTypeId == Microsoft.Maps.MapTypeId.birdseye) {
    bingMap.setMapType(Microsoft.Maps.MapTypeId.aerial);
 }
}
The above works, however the only issue I have is with my CSS hack is that IE6 & IE7 don't appear to support css3 selectors. Not a huge issue as only means that users with these can't turn off labels in the Birds eye view.

Answer (score 6):

**Sample code:**

```
map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById('myMap'),
{
  credentials: 'Your Bing Maps Key',
  disableBirdseye:true
});
```

here are some working examples from the iSDK:

http://www.bingmapsportal.com/isdk/ajaxv7#CreateMapWithMapOptions14

**API Reference:**

And here is the MSDN: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg427603.aspx

```
disableBirdseye
```

boolean
A boolean indicating whether to disable the bird’s eye map type. The default value is false. If this property is set to true, bird’s eye will be removed from the map navigation control and the birdseyeMapTypeId is disabled. Additionally, the auto map type will only display road or aerial.

This property can only be set when using the Map constructor.

Comment: This should be accepted as answer now that there is an API for it.

Comment: It looks like that option doesn't exist in `v8` :(

Answer (score 3):

You're correct in stating that there is no way currently using the v7 API to disable individual map styles. A possible Option #3 which is less hackish, but requires a bit more work, is to set the showMapTypeSelector property of the MapOptions to false, which would have the effect of hiding the entire map style selection dropdown. Then create your own custom navigation menu that only includes links to those styles you want to allow the user to choose.

Comment: +1 that's the only "officially supported" way so far, especially as the dropdown element is global (unlike the rest of the html entities created by each Map object), not specific per Map object (so if you have several maps in a single page with different settings, you're screwed unless you make your own dropdown).

Comment: Nice answer @Alastair, unfortunately I can't +1 it as my rep is so low :-( I didn't use this solution as I implemented a quick and dirty fix.